# Comparing two vectors to get common elements/defining user1 and user2

Tags: c++, visual-c++, object, vector, stdvector

i have a User class with the private users to personalize the profile of the user eg name,age,favourites. i would like to compare the favourites of two given users and output the common favourites. since i'll be using a vector for this, My question is how do i group the users to vector (user1,user2) so i can compare the favourites of any given member and output the result. this is what i have so far

### user.cpp

```
 using namespace std;

 vector<string> user;


 int  adduser();
 int adduser()
 {

   ofstream thefile;  
   thefile.open("users.txt", ios::app);

   string firstname;
   string lastname;
   int age;
   string favourites;

   cout<<"Enter your  Name: ";
   cin>>name;
   thefile << name << ' ';

   cout<<"Enter your age: ";

   cin>>age;
   thefile << age << ",";

   cout<<"Enter your favourites: ";

   cin>>favourites;
   thefile << favourites<< ",";

   thefile.close();
   cout<<" Completed."<<endl;
   return 0;
 }
 common favourites()
 {

 //how do make it so i have something like user1 and user2 
 //which are both vectors so when i enter the name of 
 //user1 and user2 i can compare thier favourites and output the common ones


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this for starters.  I'm not convinced that you need to use a vector.  I tend to prefer deque or list unless there is some reason that the data elements need to be contiguous in memory.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/

I would recommend that you use the other version of the function so that you can design a functor to handle comparing the things.  You might need to define structs for the users.

```
struct user
{
   std::string firstname;
   std::string lastname;
   int age;
   std::deque<std::string> favorites;
}

std::deque<user> users[X];  // Define the constant X somewhere depending on number of users
```

You are asking a design question so obviously the answers could go on and on.  It is up to you to use the building blocks to design your program.  It isn't really clear to me based on what you have done so far what the favorites might be.  You have to define a structure to represent each user and a comparison functor or static function that can compare two user objects in the way that you want.  There are probably many ways to do this.  These are just a few ideas.  You'll have to read some C++ documentation in order to learn how to use these things.

Comment: When you need a sequence container, the default choice should be `vector`.  You don't need a reason to use it.  You need a reason *not* to use it (such as a requirement for persistent iterators).  Because if you don't have any specific requirements which a particular sequence container cannot meet, you may as well go with the one which consistently out-performs the others in almost every category, and that's vector.

Comment: That comment makes no sense to me.  How can vector outperform a list with regards to moving elements around?  Each container type has strengths and weaknesses.  Obviously, opinions vary.

Comment: Define "moving around"?  If you mean swapping elements in the container for something like sorting operations, it outperforms list (in most cases) because it's much much faster to simply access elements, because they are close together in memory, and so they tend to fit in cache easier.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `<algorithms>` library, assuming that it's ok for you to sort the vectors:

```
std::sort(user1.begin(), user1.end());
std::sort(user2.begin(), user2.end());
std::vector<string> common;

std::set_intersection(user1.begin(), user1.end(), user2.begin(), user2.end(), std::back_inserter(common));
```

Comment: would this approach get the favourites from the .txt file and output the result?because i dont know how to define user1 and user2

Comment: No, this only cares about getting the intersection between the two vectors, that is what you asked for in your question title.